# Does this property characterize members of upward-closed families?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

This problem arose in [a certain paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.03767.pdf) on combinatorial optimization I was reading, which the author claimed is "trivial". It was not trivial for me. The formulation is purely combinatorial and relatively easy to digest for people with experience in discrete mathematics. I thought I would ask here for help in providing a proof.

We fix $n \geq 1$, and work with a ground set $[n]=\{1,2,...,n\}$. For any family of sets $\mathcal{E} \subseteq 2^{[n]}$, define the *blocking family* $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{E})$ to consist of the (inclusion-wise) minimal sets $B$ such that for each $S \in \mathcal{E}$, we have $B \cap S \neq \varnothing$. In other words, these are the minimal sets intersecting with each member of $\mathcal{E}$.

Now, let $\mathcal{F} \subseteq 2^{[n]}$ be a family of sets which, in addition, is upwards-closed, in the sense that if $S \in \mathcal{F}$ then for any $T \supset S$, we have $T \in \mathcal{F}$. A useful observation here is that $\mathcal{F}$ is determined completely by its minimal sets, since it's upward closed. Let $\mathcal{F}^{\text{min}}$ denote the subfamily of minimal sets, and note that it's clear that $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{F}^{\text{min}})=\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{F})$, since by definitions sets in $\mathcal{B}(\cdot)$ are minimal.

The problem is this:

> Show that $S \in \mathcal{F}$ if and only if $B \cap S \neq \varnothing$ for each $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{F})$.

One direction here is trivial, and is in fact simply the definition of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{F})$. The other direction is rather nontrivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One direction is trivial. Now suppose that $S\notin\mathscr{F}$. Then $F\nsubseteq S$ for each $F\in\mathscr{F}^{\text{min}}$, so for each $F\in\mathscr{F}^{\text{min}}$ there is an $x_F\in F\setminus S$. Let $B=\{x_F:F\in\mathscr{F}^{\text{min}}\}$; then $B\in\mathscr{B}(\mathscr{F}^{\text{min}})=\mathscr{B}(\mathscr{F})$, but $B\cap S=\varnothing$.